# Linking problem with wrapper for CLucene

Tags: c++, clucene

I'm doing a small wrapper from CLucene.

**ofxCLucene.h**

```
#ifndef _OFXCLUCENE_
#define _OFXCLUCENE_

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofxXmlSettings.h"
#include "ofxDirList.h"
#include "CLucene.h"

using namespace lucene;
using namespace lucene::analysis;
using namespace lucene::analysis::standard;
using namespace lucene::index;
using namespace lucene::document;
using namespace lucene::queryParser;
using namespace lucene::search;
using namespace lucene::store;


class ofxCLucene {
private:
  string name;
  SimpleAnalyzer *sanalyzer; 
  Directory *dir;
  IndexWriter *writer;
  IndexReader *reader;

public:
  ofxCLucene(string name);
  ~ofxCLucene();

  void addDocumentsFromDirectory(string pathToDir);
  void addDocumentXML(ofxXmlSettings *docXML);

  void indexReader();
  void closeIndex();

  Hits* search(string query); 

};

#endif
```

**ofxCLucene.cpp**

```
#include "ofxCLucene.h"

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ofxCLucene::ofxCLucene(string name) {
  this->name = name;
  sanalyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();
}

...
```

I have no problem compile it however when I put it on my project and create a new object I got the errors:

```
 "vtable for lucene::analysis::Analyzer", referenced from:


      __ZTVN6lucene8analysis8AnalyzerE$non_lazy_ptr in ofxCLucene.o


     (maybe you meant: __ZTVN6lucene8analysis8AnalyzerE$non_lazy_ptr)


  "vtable for lucene::analysis::SimpleAnalyzer", referenced from:


      __ZTVN6lucene8analysis14SimpleAnalyzerE$non_lazy_ptr in ofxCLucene.o


     (maybe you meant: __ZTVN6lucene8analysis14SimpleAnalyzerE$non_lazy_ptr)


ld: symbol(s) not found


collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The source code from both is:

```
class Analyzer:LUCENE_BASE{
public:

    virtual TokenStream* tokenStream(const TCHAR* fieldName, CL_NS(util)::Reader* reader)=0;

    virtual ~Analyzer(){
    }

    virtual int32_t getPositionIncrementGap(const TCHAR* fieldName);
};



class SimpleAnalyzer: public Analyzer {
public:
    TokenStream* tokenStream(const TCHAR* fieldName, CL_NS(util)::Reader* reader);
    ~SimpleAnalyzer(){}
};
```

I thought it was a namespace issue and I try calling

```
analyzer::SimpleAnalyzer *sanalyzer = new analyzer::SimpleAnalyzer();
```

but the problem remain.

Suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid using namespace in header file.

Comment: @Xavier V. - If don't put "using namespace lucene::analysis;" for example on the header file, it gives an error. Where should I put?

Comment: Using namespace in cpp file is OK. For header file, use explicit namespacing. For example :

using namespace std;
string myString;

Should be replaced by : 

std::string myString;

Answer (score 0):

This is on mac, I'm guessing? I'm not very familiar with compiling on mac.

Can you tell us how you're compiling (i.e. what compile flags, etc). And perhaps add an example which is compilable).

Also, can you compile this code using your environment?

```
#include "CLucene.h"
int main(){
   lucene::analysis::SimpleAnalyzer *sanalyzer = new lucene::analysis::SimpleAnalyzer();
}
```

I compiled the above code with the following command with no problems. (-fPIC because i'm on an 64 bit machine).

> g++ test.cpp -lclucene -I/usr/lib -fPIC